# Sails.js Node server req.session is always empty, using Passport-local strategy.

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, sails.js, passport.js

Have ember app running on `http://localhost:4200`.
Sails App is running on `http://localhost:1337`.

I have a policy set on a pre-signup survey. So on the sails side in`/api/controllers/ProcessSurveyController.js` I have this:

```
module.exports = {

    process_survey: function(req, res){
        if(req.body === {} || req.body === null){
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({err: "something bad happened"});
        }
        var params = req.body;
        req.session.user = {};
        if(params.p_1 === '1' && params.p_2 === '1' && params.p_3 === '0' && params.p_4 !== "Bad Param"){
            req.session.user.qualifies = true;
            res.status(200);
            return res.send({message: 'user qualifies', status: 'good'});   
        }else{
            req.session.user.qualifies= false;
            res.status(200);
            return res.send({message: "user fails to qualify", status: "bad"});
        }
    }
};
```

I then have this policy in `api/policies/Qualifies.js`

```
module.exports= function(req, res, next){
    if(req.session.user.qualifies){
        return next();
    }else{
        res.status(400);
        return res.send({status: 400, message: 'User does not qualify.'});
    }
};
```

Which I apply to my `api/UserController.js`

Only thing is that whenever I post from Ember to my `UserController.create` method I get an error from that policy saying `cannot read property qualifies of undefined.`

And if I `sails.log.verbose(req.session)` it's always empty at this point. No matter what I do.

I've enabled `cors` on my server, and my `/config/cors.js` has these options:

```
module.exports.cors = {
   allRoutes: true,

   origin: 'http://localhost:4200',

   credentials: true,

   methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',

   headers: 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept'
};
```

In my ember adapter I have this:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:1337',
    ajax: function(url, method, hash){
        hash.crossDomain = true;
        hash.xhrFields = {withCredentials: true};
        return this._super(url, method, hash);
    }
});
```

Clearly I'm missing something important but I just don't know what, and I've run out of ideas for google queries. 
**Why is my req.session always empty?**

**EDIT:** These were asked for in comments:

Contents of `/config/http.js`:

```
module.exports.http = {
    middleware: {
        passportInit: require('passport').initialize(),
        passportSession: require('passport').session(),

        order: [
            'startRequestTimer',
            'cookieParser',
            'session',
            'passportInit',
            'passportSession',
            'myRequestLogger',
            'bodyParser',
            'handleBodyParserError',
            'compress',
            'methodOverride',
            'poweredBy',
            '$custom',
            'router',
            'www',
            'favicon',
            '404',
            '500'
        ]
}
```

And `/config/session.js`

```
module.exports.session = {
  secret: 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',

  cookie: {
    maxAge: 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you  have a session configured? That's inside `config/http.js` & `config/session.js`

Comment: @Bwaxxlo added those files to question.

Comment: First of all, this will never evaluate to true `if(req.body === {})`. `{} !== {}`, object are compared by reference and not through properties. 

Secondly, comment out `cookieParser` & `session` in `config/http.js` because you're using your own special middleware (i.e: Passport)

Comment: Also, if you're following [this tutorial](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/), please make sure you've created `config/passport.js`

Comment: @Bwaxxlo the compare there was an edit for StackOverflow, not how it is in my code. I did go off that tutorial and I did create a `config/passport.js`. That is interesting about commenting out `session` and `cookieParser` since that's not anything I've seen in sails documentation or in that tutorial. I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Another error: `var params = req.body` should be `var params = req.params`.

Basically, `cookieParser` & `session` are using Express directly. If you already have your own session manager, there's no point of using them.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo since it's a post, `req.body` actually works, otherwise I would do `req.params.all()`.

Comment: `https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/9cbd68c95839da480e97` might help

Comment: I have found JWT to be more reliable. Ember Simple Auth and Waterlock work together quite nicely

Comment: are there any overrides in .sailsrc? Such as disabling session

Comment: [this might help](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-simple-auth-with-rest-api-and-session-cookie/7485/5) and why not use sails as a single server?

Comment: I remember facing the same issue when I followed this tutorial. :( It might be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is still an issue since it's so old, but there are times in my ExpressJS apps where I use express-session (https://github.com/expressjs/session) and have to explicitly call req.session.save(callback) in order for the session to save back to the store I'm using. If there is an equivalent in passport's session support you might try to call it explicitly after updating values in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Get` in the custom controller.

So for example,

instead of:

```
process_survey: function(req, res){
         console.log(req.session)
}
```

write:

```
"Get process_survey": function(req, res){
         console.log(req.session)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added session back into an existing Sails-app. In my case the problem was that the session was disabled via `.sailsrc` file (which of course took me some time to spot). In case of this issue: just remove the `"session": false` line from that file and `session`-property gets added.